# Android Меню

Tags: menu, android

Привет всем.
Подскажите, как включить в эмуляторе отображение кнопки меню справа?
Пытаюсь сделать этот урок http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/menu.php , но у меня в эмуляторе не отображается эта кнопка.
Делал эмулятор c этими настройками:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AopqX.png

EDIT

Меню появляется снизу при нажатии кнопки Menu на эмуляторе.
На телефоне надо будет так же нажимать отдельную кнопку или это особенности эмулятора - не отображать значок меню в правом верхнем углу?

Comment: Не понятно что конкретно не получилось. У вас ActionBar есть вообще? **android:showAsAction="never"** это устанавливает невидимость айтемов в ActionBar. Т.е. они будут вываливаться по нажатию той самой кнопки.
И покажите код метода **onCreateOptionsMenu**.

Comment: Я пока пытался просто отображение сделать, добавил такой код: 

       public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu main) {
       
       main.add("menu1");
      
       
       return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(main);
     }

И в main.xml сделал android:showAsAction="always"

Comment: Ну в таком случае установите для menu1 невидимость программно и появится та самая кнопка :)

Comment: >На телефоне надо будет так же нажимать отдельную кнопку или это особенности эмулятора?

Overflow menu появляется в виде трех точек в ActionBar когда в кнопках управления нет отдельной кнопки меню (Например на Nexus 5), если такая кнопка есть (например у LG p970) то  меню будет появляться внизу по нажатию на эту кнопку.

Nexus 5 ------------------------------------------ Lg p970

[![][1]][2][![][4]][3]

  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/51TWWcl.png
  [2]: http://i.imgur.com/nveWNDp.png
  [3]: http://i.imgur.com/RCgOWvC.png
  [4]: http://i.imgur.com/gPxWgsX.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Помоему должно быть так :

```
    Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

А в xml файле main.xml который в папке menu находится, должны быть итемы:

```
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.fotoman.myapplication321.app.MainActivity" >

<item android:id="@+id/action_one"
    android:title="@string/action_one"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_help"/>

<item android:id="@+id/action_two"
    android:title="@string/action_two"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_help"/>

<item android:id="@+id/action_three"
    android:title="@string/action_three"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_help"/>

<item android:id="@+id/action_four"
    android:title="@string/action_four"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_help"/>

    </menu>
```

Comment: А системно-сгенерированную кнопку settings удалять можно?

Comment: Да, поэксперементируй )